# Knuth-Morris-Pratt implementation in pure C

Tags: c, algorithm, implementation, knuth-morris-pratt

I have the next KMP-implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int kmp(char substr[], char str[])
{
   int i, j, N, M;

   N = strlen(str);
   M = strlen(substr);

   int *d = (int*)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
   d[0] = 0;

   for(i = 0, j = 0; i < M; i++)
   {
      while(j > 0 && substr[j] != substr[i])
      {
         j = d[j - 1];
      }

      if(substr[j] == substr[i])
      {
         j++;
         d[i] = j;
      }
   }

   for(i = 0, j = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      while(j > 0 && substr[j] != str[i])
      {
         j = d[j - 1];
      }

      if(substr[j] == str[i])
      {
         j++;
      }

      if(j == M)
      {
         free(d);
         return i - j + 1;
      }
   }

   free(d);

   return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
   char substr[] = "World",
      str[] = "Hello World!";

   int pos = kmp(substr, str);

   printf("position starts at: %i\r\n", pos);

   return 0;
}
```

You can test it here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/d2e7b3be72083c72ed768720f4716f80

It works well on small strings, and I have tested it with a large loop, on this way all is fine.

But if I change the substring I'm searching for and the complete string to these:

```
char substr[] = "%end%",
str[] = "<h1>The result is: <%lua% oleg = { x = 0xa }
         table.insert(oleg, y) oleg.y = 5 print(oleg.y) %end%></h1>";
```

Only after first try, this implementation fails...

Please, could you help me with repairing implementation of KMP to make the algorithm work with such data in strings...

Comment: how exactly does it fail? have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: actually the algorithm is incorrect, at least some elements of `d` are left uninitialized, but simply initializing them to zero won't fix the issue, it's still incorrect. First try to debug filling of the `d` array, you should understand what this array means and make this work.

Comment: here is a simpler input substr = 'ababc', str = 'xyzabababc' the only real test of string-finding algorithms is that containing repeating characters in `substr`, otherwise it's all very simple.

Comment: @unkulunkulu this algorithm does work on some samples, if you should try: substr[] = "World", str[] = "Hello World!", it will return pos: 6 as from link ( at output ), also in this long ( pervious ) strings, with pattern %lua% - it fails on substr[] = %end%...

this implementation was got from Wikibooks

Comment: Again, in substr "World" you don't have repetitions, try my input with substr='ababc', str = 'xyzabababc', it goes into infinite loop.

Comment: @unkulunkulu you did bad, when cut link from LWS ( there was proof , that algo works on some examples )

Comment: right, returned the link

Comment: @unkulunkulu from here: http://goo.gl/vkH9x I have got, Ctrl+F "Реализация алгоритма на языке Си"

Comment: that doesn't even compile (begin undefined). Anyway, that thing is completely wrong, find a more reliable source.

Comment: @unkulunkulu where it doesn't event compile, on LWS it compiled and it compiled in MS C++ in my, where does it not compile? prove it please and give me error line from your compile, it compiles fine both in ideone in lws and everywhere it does have runtime problems, but compiles, don't lie please

Comment: It has `for(i=begin,j=0;i<N; i++)` where `begin` is undefined.

Comment: @unkulunkulu if you see, it's on site code, my code doesn't have begin variable, I have repaired it, recheck my pervicous code on LWS, there is no begin

Comment: I know that your code fixed the issue, I'm just saying that the source is not to be trusted, that's all. I would suggest you just get a decent explanation of the KMP. One of the best books on the subject in russian is Shen http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/, here item 118, you can download it legally for free using that link.

Answer (score 2):

In one place you deviate from your source, the source has

```
while(j>0 && p[j]!=p[i]) j = d[j-1];
    if(p[j]==p[i])
        j++;
        d[i]=j;
```

while you have

```
while(j > 0 && substr[j] != substr[i])
{
    j = d[j - 1];
}
if(substr[j] == substr[i])
{
    j++;
    d[i] = j;
}
```

being deceived by the source's indentation. In the source, there are no braces around the `if()` branch, so only the increment `j++;` is controlled by the `if`; `d[i] = j;` is unconditional.

Then, the source has an error, probably due to the unusual use of indices. The correct way to set up the array is

```
int *d = (int*)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
d[0] = 0;

for(i = 1, j = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    while(j > 0 && substr[j-1] != substr[i-1])
    {
        j = d[j - 1];
    }

    if(substr[j] == substr[i])
        j++;
    d[i] = j;
}
```

But it's confusing, since the setup here uses the indices `i-1` and `j-1` as well as `i` and `j` to determine `d[i]`. The usual way to implement it is different; the way it is implemented [in C#](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA.D0.B5_.D0.A1.23). Since that's the form you find in most sources, it's far easier to convince yourself of the correctness of that.